# how to differentiate between when i press enter and write 0 in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

```
Include Irvine32.inc

.data
prompt1 BYTE "Bye!", 0
prompt2 BYTE "Type an integer : ", 0

.code
MAIN PROC

    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
    call WriteString

    call ReadInt

    exit
MAIN ENDP

end main
```

I would like to end the program when I just press enter key,
And print value when I write integer value(-2^15 ~ 2^15-1).

I have a problem that I don't know how to let compiler differentiate when I write 0 value and press enter key. All of flags and registers value are same when I write 0 and press enter key. so I can't differentiate it on the code.

I could solve this problem when I call WriteChar and check whether first character is enter or not, but it was very complex code. When I wrote value in case calling WriteChar, I had to change value from string to integer.

Is there any easy way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way! You have to rewrite Irvine's `ReadInt` procedure.

The original function uses [`ReadString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm) and stores the result in `ECX`. However, due to `USES ecx edx` the former value of `ECX` will be restored at the end of the procedure. Just to change it to `USES edx` solves the problem. `ECX` contains now the size of the inputted string.

```
Include Irvine32.inc

.data
prompt1 BYTE "Bye!", 0
prompt2 BYTE "Type an integer : ", 0
promptBad BYTE "Invalid input",0

.code
MAIN PROC

    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
    call WriteString

    read:
    call myReadInt

    jo  error
    jecxz error

    call WriteInt
    exit

error:
    mov  edx,OFFSET promptBad
    call WriteString
    exit
MAIN ENDP

myReadInt PROC USES edx
LOCAL digitBuffer[50]:BYTE

    lea   edx, digitBuffer
    mov   ecx,50
    call  ReadString
    mov   ecx,eax   ; save length in ECX

    call    ParseInteger32  ; returns EAX, CF

    ret
myReadInt ENDP

end main
```